# Unity is throwing an UnassignedReferenceException during runtime even after reference has been set

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a script for a basic pause menu. The script is passed two `GameObject`s through the inspector, each being a different menu, and alternates between setting each object as enabled while setting the other as disabled. The code had worked fine before I moved it to a different script while restructuring my codebase. The script still executes properly, but each time I perform the operation Unity throws an `UnassignedReferenceException`, telling me to set the reference to the `HUD` in the inspector. The reference is clearly set and the operation is being performed, but the error is still thrown. I have checked for other instances of the script, and none are present.

Here is the full script in question:

```
public class GameMenuHandler : MonoBehaviour
{   
    private bool paused;

    [SerializeField] private GameObject HUD;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject pauseMenu;

    void Start()
    {   
        SubscribeMethodsToEvents();
    }
    
    public void RestartLevel()
    {   
        String scene_name = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(scene_name);
    }

    public void ExitToMainMenu()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("MainMenu");
    }

    public void TogglePauseMenu()
    {
        paused = !paused;
        if (paused)
        {
            HUD.SetActive(false);
            pauseMenu.SetActive(true);
            Time.timeScale = 0f;
        }
        else
        {
            HUD.SetActive(true);
            pauseMenu.SetActive(false);
            Time.timeScale = 1f;
        }
    }

    void SubscribeMethodsToEvents()
    {
        GameEvents.current.onEscapeKeyPress += TogglePauseMenu;
    }

    void UnsubscribeMethodsFromEvents()
    {
        GameEvents.current.onEscapeKeyPress -= TogglePauseMenu;
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        UnsubscribeMethodsFromEvents();
    }
}
```

Here is the inspector view of the script:

[image]

Here is the console after the operation had been performed (successfully) numerous times:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to avoid this error is to set the condition `!= Null`. Try this:

```cs
if (HUD) HUD.SetActive(false);
```

```cs
if (HUD) HUD.SetActive(true);
```